# What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote some code:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.Component<any, any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> JSX element type `Elem` does not have any construct or call signatures

What does it mean?

Comment: Simply speaking, the type `React.Component<any, any>` used is the wrong type which remains unresolved. I used `React.FunctionComponent` and it worked for me.

Comment: React.FunctionComponent<any> worked for me.

Answer (score 388, accepted):

This is a confusion between *constructors* and *instances*.

Remember that when you write a component in React:

```
class Greeter extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello, {this.props.whoToGreet}</div>;
    }
}
```

You use it this way:

```
return <Greeter whoToGreet='world' />;
```

You *don't* use it this way:

```
let Greet = new Greeter();
return <Greet whoToGreet='world' />;
```

In the first example, we're passing around `Greeter`, the *constructor function* for our component. That's the correct usage. In the second example, we're passing around an *instance* of `Greeter`. That's incorrect, and will fail at runtime with an error like "Object is not a function".

---

The problem with this code

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.Component<any, any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

is that it's expecting an *instance* of `React.Component`. What you want is a function that takes *a constructor* for `React.Component`:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: new() => React.Component<any, any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

or similarly:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: typeof React.Component) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

Comment: As of this writing, if you are using `@types/react` them it's easiest to use `function RenderGreeting(Elem: React.ComponentType) { ... }`

Comment: Just curious, how do we write `function renderGreeting(Elem: typeof React.Component)` in ES6?

Comment: Thanks. What would be the case if we want to pass a stateless functional component? I guess `function renderGreeting (Elem: new() => React.SFC<any>){...}` If so why do we declare the type of SFCs like this: `const Hello:React.SFC<any> = (props) => <div>Hello World</div>`, and not: `const Hello: new() =>React.SFC<any> = (props) => <div>Hello World</div>`

Comment: @Jthorpe your comment should an answer and an accepted one at that IMO.

Comment: `export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component) => {
      const BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent = (props, { commonElements = {} }: any) => {
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} backLabel={commonElements.backLabel || 'Go back to reservation details'} />
      };
      BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent.type = WrappedComponent.type;
    
      return BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent;
    };`

I am getting an error "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof Component'".

Answer (score 96):

If you want to take a component class as a parameter (vs an instance), use `React.ComponentClass`:

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.ComponentClass<any>) {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

Comment: Now with functional components in the mix, you should probably use the `React.ComponentType<any>` type instead to be inclusive of them.

Comment: `React.ComponentType<any>` perfectly worked from my side.

Comment: React.ComponentType<any> this works for me and the simple answer thanks @RutikPatel

Answer (score 73):

The following worked for me: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631#issuecomment-472606019 I fix it by doing something like this:

```
const Component = (isFoo ? FooComponent : BarComponent) as React.ElementType
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot. <3

Comment: you might not have to type as `React.ElementType`. it might be enough to check if the components (i.e., `FooComponent` `BarComponent`) are falsy. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452966/typescript-3-jsx-element-type-component-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-s

Comment: How can you pass props to FooComponent or BarComponent?

Comment: @AdriánRodriguez  pass it in Component like: <Component name='John' age={55} />

Comment: @Sergii Like
 const Component = (isFoo ? <FooComponent name='John'/>: BarComponent) as React.ElementType
?

Comment: @AdriánRodriguez, first you add component with ternary like Warao described: const Component = (isFoo ? FooComponent : BarComponent) as React.ElementType and then when you use your component Component just pass props as usual: <Component name='John' age={55} />

Answer (score 62):

If you are using a **Functional Component** and passing a component as prop, for me the solution was changing **React.ReactNode to React.ElementType**

```
interface Props{
  GraphComp: React.ElementType
}

const GraphCard:React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { GraphComp } = props;

  return (
   <div> <GraphComp /> </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I was using JSX.Element while sending a component as prop. This helped there

Answer (score 46):

When I'm converting from JSX to TSX and we keep some libraries as js/jsx and convert others to ts/tsx I almost always forget to change the js/jsx import statements in the TSX\TS files from

`import * as ComponentName from "ComponentName";`

to

`import ComponentName from "ComponentName";`

If calling an old JSX (React.createClass) style component from TSX, then use

`var ComponentName = require("ComponentName")`

Comment: I think you meant the other way around?

Comment: Changing the inport statement is not needed if you configure TypeScript (i.e in `tsconfig.json`) to `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html  and discussion here: http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2016/10/myth-of-superset.html#comment-2936077278

Answer (score 44):

If you are passing functional component as props to another component use following:

```
import React from 'react';

type RenderGreetingProps = {
  element: React.FunctionComponent<any>
};

function RenderGreeting(props: RenderGreetingProps) {
  const {element: Element} = props;

  return <span>Hello, <Element />!</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If you really don't care about props then the widest possible type is `React.ElementType`.

This would allow passing native dom elements as string. `React.ElementType` covers all of these:

```
renderGreeting('button');
renderGreeting(() => 'Hello, World!');
renderGreeting(class Foo extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return 'Hello, World!'
   }
});
```

Comment: React.ReactType is now deprecated and React.ElementType should be used instead.

Answer (score 16):

Looks like there is now a special new TypeScript type to address the need of this question: `JSXElementConstructor`. If you are letting someone pass in the constructor to an unknown ReactElement rather than an instance of that ReactElement this is the correct type to pass.

```js
const renderGreeting = (Elem: JSXElementConstructor<any>) => {
    return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

This is equivalent to the above selected correct answer because: using `<Elem />` in JSX (aka wrapping a capital case variable with angle brackets) is equivalent to calling the constructor of a JSX Element with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using **material-ui**, go to type definition of the component, which is being underlined by TypeScript. Most likely you will see something like this

```
export { default } from './ComponentName';
```

You have 2 options to resolve the error:

1.Add `.default` when using the component in JSX:

```
import ComponentName from './ComponentName'

const Component = () => <ComponentName.default />
```

2.Rename the component, which is being exported as "default", when importing:

```
import { default as ComponentName } from './ComponentName'

const Component = () => <ComponentName />
```

This way you don't need to specify `.default` every time you use the component.

Comment: This helped me in fixing my issue.

Answer (score 12):

This is question the first result when I search for the error, so I would like to share the solution in my particular case:

The library I'm using look like this:

```js
export { default as Arc } from './shapes/Arc';
```

I imported it incorrectly, which cause the error:

```js
import Arc from "@visx/shape";
```

What it should be is

```js
import { Arc } from "@visx/shape";
```

Answer (score 10):

As @Jthorpe alluded to, `ComponentClass` only allows either `Component` or `PureComponent` but not a `FunctionComponent`.

If you attempt to pass a `FunctionComponent`, typescript will throw an error similar to...

```sh
Type '(props: myProps) => Element' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: myProps, context?: any): Component<myProps, any, any>'.
```

However, by using `ComponentType` rather than `ComponentClass` you allow for both cases. Per the react declaration file the type is defined as...

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P, any> | FunctionComponent<P>
```

Answer (score 5):

When declaring React Class component, use `React.ComponentClass`  instead of `React.Component` then it will fix the ts error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was using `React.ReactNode` as a type for a functional component instead of `React.FC` type.

In this component to be exact:

```js
export const PropertiesList: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  const list:string[] = [
    ' Consequat Phasellus sollicitudin.',
    ' Consequat Phasellus sollicitudin.',
    '...'
  ]

  return (
    <List
      header={<ListHeader heading="Properties List" />}
      dataSource={list}
        renderItem={(listItem, index) =>
          <List.Item key={index}> {listItem } </List.Item>
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent (
  WrappedComponent: React.FunctionComponent | React.ComponentClass
) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <WrappedComponent />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing `new` inside the type definition.

`some-js-component.d.ts` file:

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class SomeJSXComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    new (props: any, context?: any)
}
```

and inside the `tsx` file where I was trying to import the untyped component:

```
import SomeJSXComponent from 'some-js-component'

const NewComp = ({ asdf }: NewProps) => <SomeJSXComponent withProps={asdf} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
function renderGreeting(props: {Elem: React.Component<any, any>}) {
    return <span>Hello, {props.Elem}!</span>;
}
```

However, does the following work?

```js
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.ComponentType) {
    const propsToPass = {one: 1, two: 2};

    return <span>Hello, <Elem {...propsToPass} />!</span>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is **react-monaco-editor**, then try:

**Before**:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';
```

**Solution (After)**:

```
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor/src/index';
```

The problem is the wrong way of importing.

Error tag: JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: I understand that the problem from the topic here is not related to the Monaco library, but I found this topic when I was looking for a solution related to Monaco and decided to help people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
function renderGreeting(Elem: React.ElementType) {
  return <span>Hello, <Elem />!</span>;
}
```

would fix it (note `React.ElementType` type).

---

I had the same error, but in my case, I forgot to add the parameter parenthesis to my element.

So it was like

```js
const SomeElement = (<div> ... </div>)
```

but it should've been

```js
const SomeElement = () => (<div> ... </div>)
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by making use of ***Type Assertions*** before exporting the component. TypeScript wasn't able to identify after composing it using redux 'compose' therefore I divided props types into IParentProps and IProps and use ***IParentProps while doing Type Assertions***

```
import { compose } from 'react-redux'
import HOC1 from 'HOCs/HOC1'
import HOC2 from 'HOCs/HOC2'

type IParentProps = {}
type IProps = {}

const Component: React.FC<IProps & IParentProps> = React.memo((props) => {

      return <SomeComponent {...props}/>

})

return compose(HOC1,HOC2)(Component) as React.FunctionComponent<IParentProps>
```

Comment: I used my own compose function instead of using the redux compose function to solved this issue:
 `const compose = <R>(fn1: (a: R) => R, ...fns: Array<(a: R) => R>) =>
    fns.reduce((prevFn, nextFn) => value => prevFn(nextFn(value)), fn1);`

Answer (score -3):

Use `React.ElementType`

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631#issuecomment-472606019

Answer is too short, so, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus cursus dui vel consequat gravida. In ut tortor porttitor, maximus lectus ut, lacinia magna. Mauris vel elementum urna. Quisque arcu est, congue in urna quis, rhoncus interdum ante. Vivamus vel ornare neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur egestas rhoncus lectus eu eleifend.

Comment: The reason your answer is "too short" is because, well, it's too short. The system was right to block you. Links can die, even GitHub ones. Consider updating your answer so that it contains an excerpt as blockquote from the link you're pointing to, and try explain why `React.ElementType` is the better choice.

Comment: this was my issue, thanks for the fix! also LOL on the lorem ipsum!

Answer (score -6):

#### It is because of syntax

Here is an example to use TSX:

```
const SomeMadeComponent = (props: { someText: string }) => {
  const { someText} = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{someText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And you use it like a normal component:

`<SomeMadeComponent someText='Place your text here' />`

Comment: I don't see how this comes close to answering the OP's question? They're talking about someone passing in a special Element within the render function. Your's just renders hardcoded "Some text" on the page with always the exact same HTML markup.

Comment: You're right, but it is easy to figure out that you can pass an argument to the variable function and render it. I encountered this error and the problem was the syntax.