# import jsx file in tsx compilation error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am trying to import jsx file in tsx file. This is causing the error

> error TS2604: JSX element type 'Test' does not have any construct or
>   call signatures.

I a using webpack , react, typescript, Import  tsx files no issues, but any jsx file is causing compilation error,

package.json

```
{
  "name": "typescript-babel-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple lightweight TypeScript + Babel + Webpack project.",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },

  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "inline-style-prefixer": "^2.0.4",
    "react-style-proptype": "^1.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "@types/react": "^0.14.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.19"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "event-emitter-es6": "^1.1.5",
    "inline-style-prefixer": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-style-proptype": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
     "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
     "allowJs":true

   },   "exclude": [
     "node_modules"   ] }
```

webpack.json

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [ './src/index.tsx'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.ts','.tsx','.css']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/,loader: "style!css" },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },

      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/}
    ]
  }
};
```

I was able to make it work by wrapping ReactComponenet from   jsx in a function  and use it in tsx.  here is the code

tsx file

```
import * as React from  "react";
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import {componenetFactory} from './Test'

export class SplitPaneCom  extends   React.Component<any,any>{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){

    let componentInstance=componenetFactory();
    return componentInstance;
  }

}

ReactDom.render(<SplitPaneCom/>,document.getElementById("jumboTron"));
```

jsx file

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export  class TestComponenet extends  Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    render(){
        return (<div>Testzcdf content</div>);
    }
}

export let componenetFactory=function(){
    return <TestComponenet/>
}
```

If I try to use TestComponenet  directly I get error, I am wrapping it in function and calling it in tsx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call)

Comment: Usually googling for specific error messages will give you the result you want. Please try that first.

Comment: For future searchers, I think this has the answer - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html (i.e just rename your jsx to tsx and have `"jsx": "react"`, in your tsconfig.json

Comment: have fix for this problem? i have same problem

Answer (score -2):

I create the jsx from tsx and after decide if use it. Or another component. You can look at the code on this [github repository.](https://github.com/sabatinim/fe_architecture)