# How to properly use interfaces in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, react-redux

I came across a problem concerning interfaces and Typescript. The following example:
    import * as React from "react";

```
/*
 * An interface used to describe the properties of the react component.
 */
interface IUnsafeComponentProps {
    component: IUnsafeComponent //& typeof React.Component;
}

/*
 * An interface used to describe every component that is allowed to be rendered. 
 * It needs to define a property called "componentName".
 */
export interface IUnsafeComponent {
    componentName: string;
    componentStyles?: {};
}

/*
 * The React component itself used to render the unsafe component.
 */
export class UnsafeComponent extends React.Component<IUnsafeComponentProps, any> implements IUnsafeComponent {

    public componentName: string;

    constructor(props: IUnsafeComponentProps) {
        super(props);
        this.componentName = "UnsafeComponent";
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <this.props.component/>;
    }
}
```

The reason for such a wrapper is to allow to render third party code within my application. If I now try to use the component:

```
let content = <UnsafeComponent component={UnsafeComponent}/>;
ReactDOM.render(content, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I get the following error message:

> Type 'typeof UnsafeComponent' is not assignable to type 'IUnsafeComponent'.
>
> [0]   Property 'componentName' is missing in type 'typeof UnsafeComponent'.

I have really no idea why my ddeclaraion is wrong. I am quite new to Typescript/Javascript. Maybe I am getting something very basic wrong here.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration says you want an *instance* of `IUnsafeComponent`:

```
interface IUnsafeComponentProps {
    component: IUnsafeComponent //& typeof React.Component;
}
```

Here, you passed *the constructor function* for `UnsafeComponent`:

```
<UnsafeComponent component={UnsafeComponent}/>;
```

What you probably wanted was this, which says that you want some constructor function that produces an `IUnsafeComponent`:

```
interface IUnsafeComponentProps {
    component: new(...args: any[]) => IUnsafeComponent;
}
```

See also [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call) which talks about how JSX component references are to class constructors, not class instances.

Comment: How would I combine it if I want to pass the constructor function of an object that implements IUnsafeComponent & typeof React.Component?

Comment: After reading your link I tried it with `component: new(..args: any[]) => IUnsafeComponent & React.Component<any, any>` but I can't access the `componentName` property, I get the error on the following caller code: `{this.props.component.componentName}` -> "Property 'componentName' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => IUnsafeComponent & Component<any, any>'.
"