# How can I accept a React.Component parameter in a function with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, generics, typescript, types

When I use React with TypeScript, I usually create a ES6 class to define a component like so:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface TextProps { text: string; }

export class Panel extends React.Component<TextProps, any> {
    constructor(props: TextProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <div className="panel">{this.props.text}</div>;
    }
}

export class Label extends React.Component<TextProps, any> {
    constructor(props: TextProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <span className="label">{this.props.text}</span>;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is create a type that would accept both a `Panel` or a `Label`.

I tried the following:

```
type TextComp = React.Component<TextProps, any>;

function create(component: TextComp, text: string) {
    return React.createElement(component, { text: text });
}
```

This shows compiler errors on the `React.createElement(component,` parameter but the code runs properly.

How can I define the type `TextComp` such that this code compiles without errors using TypeScript version 2.2.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
type TextComp = new(...args: any[]) => React.Component<TextProps, any>;

function create(component: TextComp, text: string) {
    return React.createElement(component, { text: text });
}
```

The root cause is the same as explained at [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call)

Comment: Very cool! Can you take it one step further and also accept React Stateless components...simply a function like `type type Stateless = (props: TextProps) => JSX.Element;`? When I tried to union your TextComp type with my Stateless type, `React.createElement` was complaining at me again :/