# JSX element does not have construct or call signatures for react-timekeeper

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TimeKeeper from 'react-timekeeper';


export class Modal extends React.Component<any, any>{
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        time: '',
        displayTimepicker: false
    }
    this.handleTimeChange = this.handleTimeChange.bind(this)
}

handleTimeChange(newTime: any) {
    this.setState({ time: newTime.formatted })
}
toggleTimekeeper(val: any) {
    this.setState({ displayTimepicker: val })
}

public render() {
    return (
        <div className="textalign-center">
            <table className="modaltable">
                <tr>
                    <span className="timemodal-span" readOnly={true} onClick={() => this.toggleTimekeeper(true)}>{
                        (this.state.time == '')
                            ?
                            "Select Time"
                            :
                            this.state.time
                    }
                    </span>
                    {
                        this.state.displayTimepicker ?
                            <TimeKeeper
                                time={this.state.time}
                                onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
                                onDoneClick={() => {
                                    this.toggleTimekeeper(false)
                                }}
                                switchToMinuteOnHourSelect={true}
                                closeOnMinuteSelect={true}
                            />
                            :
                            false
                    }
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div >
    )
}
```

}

In this configuration I have the following error:

> Could not find declaration file for module 'react-timekeeper'. Try 'npm install @types/react-timekeeper' if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing 'declare module 'react-timekeeper';'

There is no @types install for react-timekeeper. So I tried switching

> import Timekeeper from 'react-timekeeper';

to

> const TimeKeeper = require('react-timekeeper');

But now I get the following error:

> JSX element TimeKeeper does not have any constructs or call signatures.

I looked at similar threads but the solutions seemed to be component specific. Any general way to fix these errors?

EDIT:
Tried the following:

```
    public render() {
        var gettimekeeper = (TimeKeeper: new () => React.Component<any, any>) => {
        return <TimeKeeper
            time={this.state.time}
            onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
            onDoneClick={() => {
                this.toggleTimekeeper(false)
            }}
            switchToMinuteOnHourSelect={true}
            closeOnMinuteSelect={true}
        />
    };
    return (
        <div className="textalign-center">
            <table className="modaltable">
                <tr className="statbox">
                    <td>
                          {gettimekeeper}
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <span className="timemodal-span" readOnly={true} onClick={() => this.toggleTimekeeper(true)}>{
                        (this.state.time == '')
                            ?
                            "Select Time"
                            :
                            this.state.time
                    }
                    </span>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div >
    )
```

It does not work.

Comment: Maybe this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call

Comment: Now it just seems to return an empty object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call)