# TypeScript 3: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures. [2604]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm trying to pass a variable of type React.Component (or React.FunctionComponent) into a Route, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component: React.Component | React.FunctionComponent;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  login: (...args: any[]) => any;
  path: string;
};

const PrivateRoute: React.FunctionComponent<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  isAuthenticated,
  login,
  path,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          login();
          return null;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

But I'm getting this error:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures. [2604]

I've read through a bunch of other threads about this issue, but they all seem to deal with this error coming up for a specific component implementation. I can't change the component in question or import it differently (like the accepted answers often suggest), because it could be *any* component.

I'm using TypeScript 3.1.6, Babel Core 7.1, and React 16.6.3.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have encountered this a couple of times. Try these:

1. Type your `PrivateRoute` as `React.FC<Props>`
2. Type your incoming component as `React.ElementType`

The ultimate truth about React types comes from [the docs](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts)

Edit: React.ReactType (deprecated) -> React.ElementType

Comment: #2 worked for me. Now it's time to do some research and figure out exactly why it worked. Thanks for the link to the docs, too.

Comment: `export const BackNavigationTextWrapper = (WrappedComponent: typeof React.Component) => { const BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent = (props, { commonElements = {} }: any) => { return <WrappedComponent {...props} backLabel={commonElements.backLabel || 'Go back to reservation details'} /> }; BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent.type = WrappedComponent.type; return BackNavigationTextWrappedComponent; }; `I am getting an error "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'typeof Component'".

Comment: Tried the React.ReactType and it works, but it seems to be deprecated, so the currently appropriate type is `React.ElementType`. No errors in VS Code with it.

Answer (score 62):

Late to the party, with `"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.4"` and `"@types/react": "16.9.1"`, and if you're using `RouteProps`, you will probably get the same error.

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures. [2604]

That's because, in the `RouteProps` interface, the `component` is defined as optional, hence it might be undefined.

```js
export interface RouteProps {
  location?: H.Location;
  component?: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>> | React.ComponentType<any>;
  render?: ((props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => React.ReactNode);
  children?: ((props: RouteChildrenProps<any>) => React.ReactNode) | React.ReactNode;
  path?: string | string[];
  exact?: boolean;
  sensitive?: boolean;
  strict?: boolean;
}
```

Simply check for if the `component` is falsy will fix it.

```js
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }: RouteProps) {
  if (!Component) return null;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't generally write useless "thank you" comments but THANK YOU! I've been digging pretty deep and this is the only thing that's mentioned conditionality as a potential problem and it solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you, this was really useful! I didn't realize of this :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no need to set type as `React.ElementType`.

Answer (score 16):

Even later to the party, but what worked for me is this:

```js
interface PrivateRouteProps extends Omit<RouteProps, "component"> {
  component: React.ElementType;
  // any additional vars
}

PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
// render code
}
```

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer because this protects from using PrivateRoute without component.

Answer (score 5):

This is late but in case someone didn't want a solution but an explanation, let's talk about this error using an example to demonstrate it

```
function PaymentPage(){
  
   return <div>Payment Page</div>
}
```

say we want to create a dynamic payment form, if the query parameter is with=stripe so we assume he wants to pay with stripe, if it's with razorpay we assume it, ...etc.

we then do something like

```
function PaymentPage(){
   const router = useRouter;
   const {with_} = router.query;
   let GatewayComponent: Gateway | null = null;
   switch(with_){
     case 'stripe':
       GatewayComponent = <StripeGateway/>;
       break;
     case 'razorpay':
       GatewayComponent = <RazorpayGateway/>;
       break;
   }
   return <GatewayComponent/>
}
```

Running this, we get

```
JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

What happens?

### What are component?

- Constructors that return elements of type JSX.Element

### So?

- We are not returning a *constructor*, we are returning a *Constructor call*, it's the same as assuming that `GatewayComponent` is a constructor, but it's not, it's a variable holding JSX

So basically,  expects x to be a constructor of any type, either a function or a class, if it's a function, the function is the render function, if it's a class, it needs a render method.

### Back to our problem

```
function PaymentPage(){
   const router = useRouter;
   const {with_} = router.query;
   let gateway: Gateway | null = null;
   switch(with_){
     case 'stripe':
       gateway = <StripeGateway/>;
       break;
     case 'razorpay':
       gateway = <RazorpayGateway/>
       break;
   }
   return <React.Fragment> {gateway} </React.Fragment>
}
```

Because gateway holds JSX, not a constructor that returns JSX

### What if you want to use it as a component?

```
function PaymentPage(){
   const router = useRouter;
   const {with} = router.query;
   let GatewayComponent: Gateway | null = null;
   switch(with_){
     case 'stripe':
       return () => <StripeGateway/>
     case 'razorpay':
       return () => <RazorpayGateway/>
   }
   return <GatewayComponent/>
}
```

Now it's a constructor, we can use it as a component right now.

*Formally*, you pass the constructor and not the instance.

Comment: I did not follow this at all.  Your examples don't resemble the original question, so I don't know how to relate it.  And which line is returning the error?

Answer (score 2):

**<PrivateRoute path="'/>** 
 **Path** gave an error while  using **interface PrivateRouteProps** then i switched it to

````
export type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component: React.ElementType;
  currentUser?: any;
} & RouteProps;```
````

**Final result below**

```
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
export type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component: React.ElementType;
  currentUser?: any;
} & RouteProps;

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  currentUser,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: Worked great for me

Comment: This worked great for me but I modified it a little bit by making component optional.
 
 
```type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component?: React.ElementType
} & RouteProps```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error by typing my component as follows:

```
...
export function withApollo (PageComponent: () => JSX.Element) {
const WithApollo = <T extends object>(props: T) => {
...
```