# When passing component as prop i get TS2604 error when i try and render it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a component as a prop to another component
The idea is I can pass the component to wrap the content of a modal (from material ui) with

Here is what i have tried

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withWidth, { isWidthDown } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import MuiDialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import { Breakpoint } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints";
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import ButtonSpinner from './ButtonSpinner';

interface OwnProps {
  title: string
  open: boolean
  content: React.ReactNode
  isRunning: boolean
  confirmText: string
  declineText: string
  innerWrapper?: React.ReactNode
  innerWrapperProps?: any
  contentWrapper?: React.ReactNode
  onClose(): void
  onConfirm(): void
  onDecline(): void
  width: Breakpoint;
}

const InnerWrapperDefault: React.ReactNode = (p: any) => (
  <React.Fragment {...p} />
);
const ContentWrapperDefault: React.ReactNode = (p: any) => (
  <DialogContent {...p} />
);

class Dialog extends Component<OwnProps> {
  renderContent = () => {
    const { content } = this.props;

    switch (typeof content) {
      case 'string':
        return <DialogContentText>{content}</DialogContentText>;
      case 'function':
        return content();
      default:
        return content;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      content,
      children,
      onClose,
      onConfirm = null,
      onDecline = null,
      confirmText = 'Enig',
      declineText = 'Uenig',
      isRunning = false,
      width,
      innerWrapper: InnerWrapper = InnerWrapperDefault,
      innerWrapperProps = null,
      contentWrapper: ContentWrapper = ContentWrapperDefault,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiDialog
        fullScreen={isWidthDown('xs', width) ? true : undefined}
        onClose={onClose}
        disableBackdropClick={isRunning}
        disableEscapeKeyDown={isRunning}
        aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
        {...rest}
      >
        <InnerWrapper {...innerWrapperProps}>
          <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">{title}</DialogTitle>
          <ContentWrapper>
            {content && this.renderContent()}
            {children}
          </ContentWrapper>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={onDecline || onClose} color="primary" disabled={isRunning}>
              {declineText}
            </Button>
            {onConfirm &&
              <ButtonSpinner isRunning={isRunning}>
                <Button onClick={onConfirm} color="primary" autoFocus disabled={isRunning}>
                  {confirmText}
                </Button>
              </ButtonSpinner>
            }
          </DialogActions>
        </InnerWrapper>
      </MuiDialog>
    );
  }
}

export default withWidth()(Dialog);
```

When i try this Typescript throws an error on InnerWrapper and ContentWrapper with

JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Any suggestions how i can make this work?

**EDIT: Added call example**
Could be called with something like this

```
return (
<Dialog
        confirmText="Yes"
        declineText="No"
        title="Dialog title"
        content="Dialog content"
        innerWrapper: (p: any) => <React.Fragment {...p} />,
    />
)
```

Comment: Where do the types `InnerWrapper` and `ContentWrapper` come from? You're not importing or creating them.

Comment: Destructed from this.props inside render method

Comment: I mean the types, not the variable. You have `innerWrapper: InnerWrapper = InnerWrapperDefault`, but I can't see where your type declaration (meaning `InnerWrapper`) comes from. It is `varName: type = defaultValue`

Comment: hmm well im kinda new to typescript but i made that inteface for OwnProps at the top, is that what you are reffering to?

Comment: Where i set them to React.ReactNode

Comment: the `innerWrapper: InnerWrapper = InnerWrapperDefault` is just ES6 destructuring

Comment: How are you trying to render the `Dialog` component?

Comment: From render method of another component

Updated question with call example code

Comment: Have you tried `innerWrapper={(p: any) => <React.Fragment {...p} />}`?

Comment: Nope no difference

Comment: I tried setting innerWrapper and contentWrapper to `any` and that supresses the error, however it just feels wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think your problem is, that you are trying to use a type which does not exist.</s>

When you're deconstructing your props you try to assign `innerWrapper` and `contentWrapper` the types of `InnerWrapper` and `ContentWrapper`:

```
const {
  ...
  innerWrapper: InnerWrapper = DefaultInnerWrapper,
  contentWrapper: ContentWrapper = DefaultContentWrapper
  ...
} = this.props;
```

But those types are not defined (e.g. as an interface or imported from a module).

You should be fine if you simply remove them and deconstruct your props like this:

```
const {
  ...
  innerWrapper = DefaultInnerWrapper,
  contentWrapper = DefaultContentWrapper
  ...
} = this.props;
```

Another problem then is that you're trying to render those as components:

```
<InnerWrapper {...innerWrapperProps}/>
  ...
  <ContentWrapper/>
```

Meaning you try to create a JSX element from something that is not references. You should create a component/function for those if you want to render them. I think you can simply rename `innerWrapper` to `InnerWrapper` and `contentWrapper` to `ContentWrapper` in your props to use them as componet.

Edit: So I learned about renaming while using ES6 destructing.

But to help you: As already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call#comment90135040_31815634) you should use `React.ComponentType` instead of `React.ReactNode` as the type of your wrappers which will fix your error message.

Comment: I was trying to use ES6 destructuring where i take the prop innerWrapper from this.props and assign it to InnerWrapper and setting default value to DefaultInnerWrapper, or do typescript overrule how ES6 destructuring works?

Comment: Also i tried renaming to InnerWrapper and the error is the same

Comment: Well looks like I learned something new. I didn't know that you rename the variables after the colon! So forget my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time researching this, and glad i could learn you about destructuring in ES6 :) With that said changing type to React.ComponentType still gives an error `JSX element type 'InnerWrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures. ts(2604)`

Comment: Setting the type to any supresses the error, but that kinda defeat the purpose of using typescript imo

Comment: Setting InnerWrapperDefault and ContentWrapperDefault to the React.ComponentType along with innerWrapper and contentWrapper in interface fixed the problem