# How to fix error JSX element type 'ElemCard' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am compiling a TypeScript project which references another module, and I got the following error:

> JSX element type 'ElemCard' does not have any construct or call signatures

```
/* ClientHeartbeatCard.tsx */

import {ElemCard} from "sm2.0-genericui";

<ElemCard mr_medium
              color={color}
              hidden={props.hidden}
              backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
              iconName={FavouriteIcon}
              title={labels.heartbeat}
              primaryText={primaryText}
              secondaryText={secondaryText}
              onClick={console.log}
/>

/* ElemCard.tsx */
export interface ElemCardProps extends CardProps {
  primaryText: any;
  secondaryText?: any;
}

export const ElemCard = (props: ElemCardProps) => {
  return (
    <Card iconName={props.iconName} {...props as any}>
      <Flex column center>
        <Text gigantic bold headingFont>
          {props.primaryText}
        </Text>
        <Text secondary>
          {props.secondaryText}
        </Text>
      </Flex>
    </Card>
  )
};
```

I expect the TypeScript to be able to compile without error, but it throws the above mentioned error.  Any idea?

Comment: Change :
    ```import {ElemCard} from "sm2.0-genericui";```

To :
    ```import ElemCard from "sm2.0-genericui";```

Comment: Have a look here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call/31815634

Comment: I tried the import @OsamaKhalid, but it doesn't works

Comment: I read the link, but I don't really understand it because I am new to TypeScript

Comment: What is mr_medium ? Try removing that or assign it a value