# JSX element type 'CommonHeader' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to combine multiple HOC in my react app :

Basically :

```
const { Header } = Layout;

interface CommonHeaderProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
  t: Function
}

class CommonHeader extends React.Component<CommonHeaderProps> {  

  render() {


    return (
      <div>     
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
};

const Component = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CommonHeader)

export default compose<CommonHeader>(
 withTranslation,
 withRouter,
)(Component)
```

The problem I face is, when I try to call this component from another one in their renderer function, I have the following error

`JSX element type 'CommonHeader' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the error "JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call)

Comment: I saw that post, and I can of understand the problem, but I do not understand how to fix in my situation