# How to use an abstract class as the type of a React component in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, abstract

How can the abstract class 'Base' be used as a type definition here?

```
abstract class Base extends React.Component { /* */ }

class A extends React.Component<{
  ComponentToUse: Base
}> {
  render() {
    const { ComponentToUse } = this.props;
    // The following line gives this compile error:
    // JSX element type 'Base' does not have any construct or call signatures. ts(2604)
    return (<ComponentToUse />);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the props from

```
class A extends React.Component<{
  ComponentToUse: Base
}> {
```

to

```
class A extends React.Component<{
  ComponentToUse: typeof Base
}> {
```

See the [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31815633/7470360) for more information.