# Use Dynamic Wrapper for children React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a component passed from the props to wrap children, if defined.

```js
interface ExampleProps {
  wrapper: JSX.Element;
}

function Example({ wrapper }: ExampleProps) {
  return (
    // Wrap this with `wrapper`, only if it is defined, else don't wrap.
    <Child></Child>
  )
}
```

How can this we be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
function Example({ wrapper }) {
  if(wrapper) {
    const Wrapper = wrapper //to make it alike component
    return <Wrapper><Child></Child></Wrapper>
  }
  return (
    <Child></Child>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function Example({ wrapper, children }) {
  const Wrapper = wrapper || React.Fragment; // custom components should start with capital letter
  return (
    <Wrapper>
     {children}
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey Vishnu! Could you make this compatible with TypeScript? Currently, I have `wrapper` as `JSX.Element`. I get the following error:`JSX element type 'RowWrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Comment: It is because the wrapper is not typed. Adding this might fix the error `React.FunctionComponent<any>`.  I suggest you replace `any`. For a detailed explanation about the error, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815634/7014483
. Cheers!